# Why is email confirmation needed for OpenID accounts?

Tags: discussion, area-51, openid, login, confirmation

Maybe I'm missing something. On Area51, I first logged in with my OpenID (gmail). Attempted to vote, but was told I needed to confirm my email. Then realised I could copy my profile from StackOverflow. And yet I *still* needed to confirm my email. So:

1) If I'm logging in with a gmail OpenId, surely my email address is already "confirmed".
2) If I'm using the same profile as on StackOverflow, again, surely my email address is already "confirmed".

And finally: the whole process of logging in with an OpenId, then subsequently discovering that you can, after all, use an existing profile from another StackExchange based site is very confusing to people like me - infrequent users of these sites. I suggest the GUI people try this out some time and see the awkward series of steps.

Comment: Then to top it off, I had to answer a recaptcha too. Sorry for the rant but: 1) I logged in with OpenId, 2) I copied my profile over, 3) I confirmed my email address - and you're *still* not sure whether I'm a human being that can be trusted to ask a question. Srsly.

Comment: (Ok, so I see I'm not logged in on *this* site, even though in the next tab over I'm logged in on Area51. Wouldn't single single sign-on make life a lot easier...) I'll go away now.

Comment: you should be logged in. Not sure if Area 51 has the latest global auth code, though http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Area 51 has stricter requirements vis-a-vis confirming email, because we need to be sure the people voting for and supporting site proposals are actual *people*.

Otherwise, we might launch a site and nobody but sockpuppets would show up!

Comment: sockpuppets.stackexchange.com - A Q&A site for professional sockpuppeteers to ask questions related to sockpuppetry.

Comment: I guess that's reasonable, but the overall user experience is still very clunky. Also, if the rules are different for area51, a comment to that effect would be useful. Finally, if the OpenId you're logging in with is an email provider, does it still make sense to request email verification? Actually now that I think about it, isn't an OpenId just as good proof that you're an "actual person" as an email address is anyway? Creating email aliases is pretty easy...

Comment: @SimonPStevens Watch a puppetry proposal get subsumed into a more general one about theatrical performance.